# Responsive table layout with a static column?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to implement a responsive table design that works in as many browsers as possible. The two left most cells (left/mid) will have static width while I need the right div to have a dynamic width based on the size of the current window.

This is how the markup looks like :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftWrapper">
        <div class="left">left</div>
        <div class="mid">mid</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi velit justo non. Pretium vestibulum nibh nonummy et a libero. Aptent consequat suscipit ridiculus leo pellentesque tempus, suspendisse pretium quis turpis. Euismod facilisi congue ab. Pretium ultricies non aliquam mi, cras sint, pede elit ligula aliquam in scelerisque ultricies, vitae dictum tincidunt sit, torquent eu et eros suspendisse. Voluptate nec curabitur et at nam non, diam vel, lorem nibh id condimentum a, laborum ornare, pede sem mattis. Numquam magna non metus sit fringilla, ligula quis cras, in lorem, praesent eros volutpat nisl vehicula tellus, egestas nullam. Pede aliquam donec.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmZeN/.

How do I let right cell stay on the same line as the left and mid cell without using display: table-cell and at the same time litting it resize based on the width of the bowser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this from complete scratch, see if it's useful to you

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nuPzA/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<style>
.left {
    float: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color:#0f0;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.center { 
    float: left; 
    width: 120px;  
    background-color:#000;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.right { 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #f0f; 
    margin-left: 320px; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: I made this solution based on yours : http://jsfiddle.net/AAWtY/ it seems to work but will it work in all browsers? Even mobile? Also, why do you have 317px instead of 320px?

Comment: @SnowJim Was testing with other dimensions, as I had floated them, my right block was rendering at the bottom so later forgot to change -317.. and yes it should support

Answer (score 1):

Do not float the `.right` element and give it a margin the same width as the `.leftWrapper`

That is the beauty of the floats..

**updated demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/mmZeN/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you have static values for left and middle one, you may specify using css and let other column to be percentage value. This should work in this case.

Updated: Get the px with of current placeholder(may be a DIV), deduct left and middle column width, then remain width ex: Xpx
Xpx/total width of container x 100
this value you may give as percentage.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this? 100% will put the right column down to second row?